# Save listView items with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, listview, save, sharedpreferences

I want to receive list view items by the user. And by pressing the button, the value in the edit text will be entered into the list. and save this list. So that closing the program does not destroy the list. I am trying to use sharedPreferences. The problem is in the size. Of course, as far as I checked and tested. I would be grateful if you could give a solution for this using sharedPreferences.
sizeArrayList = sp.getInt("size",0); This line is done somewhat correctly. The problem is that by adding a new item and exiting the program, the value of this key starts from zero. As a result, the list items are not all loaded. Actually, all the items are correctly in the xml related to sharedPreferences which is in the Device File Explorer. The problem is changing the value of the "size" key.

```
package com.example.todolist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtName;
    Button btnAddAndSave, btnGo;
    ListView lsv;

    public static ArrayList<String>nameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    static public SharedPreferences sp;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int counter;
    int sizeArrayList;

    String nam;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtName = findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        btnAddAndSave = findViewById(R.id.btnAndAndSave);
        btnGo = findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
        lsv = findViewById(R.id.lsv);

        sp = getSharedPreferences("ArraySave",MODE_PRIVATE);


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameArrayList);
        sizeArrayList = sp.getInt("size",0);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeArrayList; i++){
             nam = sp.getString(i+"", "NameDef");
            nameArrayList.add(nam);
            lsv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        sp.edit().putInt("size",sizeArrayList).apply();
        btnAddAndSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameArrayList);
                String newItem = edtName.getText().toString();
                nameArrayList.add(newItem);
                for (int i = 0; i < nameArrayList.size(); i++){
                    sp.edit().putString(i+"", nameArrayList.get(i)).apply();
                    sp.edit().putInt("size",counter).apply();
                }
                counter++;

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lsv.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Well before looking at the code we would like you to tell us what exactly you try to store in shared preferences.

Comment: The user enters a string in the text editor. And after pressing the button, that string will be added to the list. Actually I want the strings to be saved.

Comment: Room DB should solve the problem and you would not have any problem with performance https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

Comment: You want to save strings. What is the problem doing so?

Comment: sizeArrayList = sp.getInt("size",0); This line is done somewhat correctly. The problem is that by adding a new item and exiting the program, the value of this key starts from zero. As a result, the list items are not all loaded. Actually, all the items are correctly in the xml related to sharedPreferences which is in the Device File Explorer. The problem is changing the value of the "size" key.

Comment: You should put all info in your post. Not afterwards in comments. Write a good post to begin with.

Comment: You can use  [`Set<String>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#putStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) instead

Answer (score 0):

I can update the listview each time without showing duplicates using a for loop. I was able to use sharedPreferences to store the values
Here you can see my solution. In the tests I did, I did not find any problems, but if you find any problems, I would be grateful if you could tell me.

```
package com.example.mynote;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.style.TtsSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnAddNote;
    ListView lsv;

    ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<>();

    SharedPreferences sp;

    EditText edtItem;
    int counter = 1;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAddNote = findViewById(R.id.btnAddNote);
        lsv = findViewById(R.id.lsv);
        edtItem = findViewById(R.id.edtItem);

        sp = getSharedPreferences("NameSubject", MODE_PRIVATE);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameArray);
        counter = sp.getInt("count", 1);
        btnAddNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String item = edtItem.getText().toString();
                sp.edit().putString("subject" + counter, item).apply();
                nameArray.add(sp.getString("subject" + counter, "s"));
                counter++;
                sp.edit().putInt("count", counter).apply();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lsv.setAdapter(adapter);
                edtItem.setText("");
            }
        });
        for (int i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
            nameArray.add(sp.getString("subject" + i, "s"));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lsv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        lsv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lsv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, nameArray.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).